# JSON String test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, json

I am using a json string like this in a test class.

```
[{
    "id":"01t4B000000XrvhQAC",
    "name":"abc123",
    "DateRange":{"startDate":"2020-02-17","endDate":"2020-02-26"}
}]
```

Now instead of hard coding id, I want to use a variable named `prdId`.

How can I do this? I tried putting `prdId` there, it says,

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:9]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omitting the rest of the structure for brevity, you can do something like the following:

```
'[{"id": "' + prId + '"}]`
```

I tend to prefer creating a class to represent the structure and then serialize that.

```
class MyObject
{
    Id id;
    String name;
    DateRange dateRange;
}
class DateRange
{
    String startDate, endDate;
}
```

Then in your test:

```
MyObject instance = new MyObject();
instance.id = prId;
instance.name = 'abc123';
instance.dateRange = new DateRange();
instance.dateRange.startDate = '2020-02-17';
instance.dateRange.endDate = '2020-02-26';
String myJSON = JSON.serialize(instance);
```

Comment: There should be \ to escape " in the string.

Comment: @VigneshwaranG You don't need to escape double quotes in `Apex`, it's wrapped in single quotes.